# Unset activity for deleted view in clearcase

Tags: clearcase

How to release activity for view that  has been deleted.

There are no reference in pvob or cvob for that removed view                                   Tried cleartool desc -l vob:/vobs/test_pvb
There are no refernece in either pvob or cvob

Answer (score 1):

You could try setting the activity to an existing view. If you do not have an existing view associated with the stream, create a new one with cleartool mkview -stream option. Then:

```
$ cleartool setact -view <new-view-tag> activity:<activity-name>@<pvob>
```

Once the activity transferred to , you could then do:

```
$ cleartool setact -view <new-view-tag> -none
```

So that the activity will not be associated with any view at all.

Answer (score 0):

The normal command to release an activity is [`cleartool setact -none -view viewtag`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_setactivity.htm?cp=SSSH27_8.0.0%2F9-1-0-2-27).

But if the view has been rmtagged as well as unregistered, that would no longer be possible.
The view would need to be at least registered  and tagged again: check if a `cleartool descr -l activity:myActivity/vobs/test_pvb` does mention anything about the view in which the activity is set.

Check also if this activity is an integration activity that is in use as part of a deliver or rebase operation: as mentioned in "[IBM technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146614)", you could not clear it that way either.